# AngularJs ui set the home page active

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-class

I am working of AngularJs v 1  app with ui routing.

My question simply how to set the home page active without clicking the ui-sref link.

I tried with ng-class="active" but it doesn't achieve the task.

```
<script>
angular.module("myApp",['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
   $stateProvider
      .state("home",{
         url:"home",
         views:{
         'main':{templateUrl:"home.html"}
      }
});
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
</script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 60px">
<div ui-view="main"> </div>
</div>
```

Home page

```
<div class="row" style=" margin-top:100px; " ng-app="app" ng-class="active">
<h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`ui-sref-active`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active)

From the doc

> A directive working alongside ui-sref to add classes to an element when the related ui-sref directive's state is active, and removing them when it is inactive. The primary use-case is to simplify the special appearance of navigation menus relying on ui-sref, by having the "active" state's menu button appear different, distinguishing it from the inactive menu items.

It will add the `active` for you if you're currently on the right state.

Markup should look something along the line of

```
<div class="some-navigation-class">
    <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a>
    <!-- more nav goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I changed  my navbar to the following code
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="c1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>  <a ui-sref="home"  style="background-color:#84b1f9; color:black;" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a></li> but that doesn't achieve the task!

Comment: did you properly configure your router? is `.active` a properly defined style ? are you at the right state ? [here is a demo showing how it's done](https://plnkr.co/edit/2SSO4Y?p=preview), it's from the official tutorials